# EditText.setOnKeyListener is not detectable on Google Pixel 8 (Android 14)

Tags: android, android-edittext, pixel

Below is a line of code that I'm using to disable "Enter" key on the soft keyboard on `EditText` multiline and it works just fine on Samsung Galaxy. However, it's doing absolutely nothing on Google Pixel 8 (Android 14), as if they have a totally different keyboard.

```
someEditText.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
```

What might be a problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here we go:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34703937/1664654

```
someEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend) -> {
        if (source != null) {
            String s = source.toString();
            if (s.contains("\n")) {
                return s.replaceAll("\n", "");
            }
        }
        return null;
}});
```